# How to migrate users without email to B2C, and prompt them to enter email on first signin using B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have a scenario where we want to migrate users from a database to Azure B2C. These users were registered using usernames, and not emails. 
The customer want their new B2C solution to only use emails, and would like these users to be prompted on their first sign-in, to provide an email.

I was thinking this could probably be done using an additional orchestration step with a precondition that checks if email exists. 
However, the issue I can’t figure out is how these users, with no email, will sign in the first time. 
We want the email to be the UPN (username) in B2C, i.e the value they sign in with, so I cannot store their old username as the UPN because then the precondition that checks for a UPN will return true, skipping the step where we ask the first-time user to enter their email.

Another solution I just thought of, could be to have the first step in the user journey be an attribute verifier step where the user enters their old username/pass, and if it is OK, it continues to the next step where we ask the user for an email. However not sure how to implement this, would I save the old username in a claim and store it in B2C as a custom attribute? (since we need this username for lookups).

Is this scenario solvable somehow?

Comment: Yes, it is solvable. But one question: After they have provided their email address, do you want to allow them to sign in using both email address and username in the future, or just username (and use email for password reset only etc.)?